# Show the number of textboxes precisely once after I enter another value to the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<title>
</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new_2.css"  type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function AddingTextBoxes() {
    var NumOfText = $("#NumOfTextBoxes").val();
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').empty();
    for (i = 1; i <= NumOfText; i++) {
    var ipBoxName = "MyInput" + i;
    var $div = $('<div/>').addClass('row jsRow');

    $('<input/>').attr('type', 'text')
                 .attr('name', 'textbx[]')
                 .attr('id',   'TxtBx_' + i)
                 .attr('value', i)
                 .addClass('txtbx')
                 .appendTo($div);

    $('<input/>').attr('type', 'text')
                 .attr('name', 'textbx[]')
                 .addClass('txtbx2')
                 .appendTo($div);

    $('<select/>').attr('id', 'SelectOption_' + i)
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Text_Box') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Text_Area') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Radio_Button') )
                  .addClass('selectbx')
                  .appendTo($div);

    $('<button/>').attr('id', 'Child_Btn_' + i)
                  .attr('value', 'B')
                  .text('Click for child selections')
                  .on('click', ChildTxtBoxes)
                  .appendTo($div);

    $('<div/>').addClass('BtnSet').appendTo($div);

    $div.appendTo($('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes'));

}
return false;
}

function ChildTxtBoxes() {
    var $this   = $(this);
    var $BtnSet = $this.closest('div').find('.BtnSet');
    var idBase  = 'TxtID_' + $this.attr('id').split('_').slice(-1) + '_';

    var retVal = prompt("Enter the number of textboxes need to add");

    console.log($BtnSet);
$BtnSet.empty();
for (i = 1; i <= retVal; i++) {
    $('<input/>').attr('id', idBase + i)
                 .attr('type', 'text')
                 .attr('name', 'textbx[]')
                 .appendTo($('<div/>').appendTo($BtnSet));
}
alert("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
<form >
<div id="PHPForms" >
<!--Designing PHP forms dynamically-->
<label>Form Heading</label><input type="text"/><br><br>
<input id="NumOfTextBoxes" type="text" value="0"></input>
<button id="addem" onclick="return AddingTextBoxes()">Add Textboxes</button>

<div id="NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes">

</div>

<div id='BtnSet'></div></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example once I `click` on "Click for child selections" button, it perfectly prints the number of text boxes I was given if I dont use `$('#BtnSet').empty();` method. But once I re-enter another value in the popup textboxes it prints the textboxes without making empty the previous set of text boxes. And if I prints use `$('#BtnSet').empty();` it prints nothing but allocates spaces. So what are the changes I should do inorder to work the function perfectly.?

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem, can you elaborate?

Comment: ya.... Once I click on one of "Click for child selections" buttons it appears a text box to enter the number of textboxes I need to create. But it doesnt work perfectly. for the first time it prints the number of text boxes wht I need. But if I re-enter a value by clicking "Click for child selections" textboxes again it  prints without making empty the previous textboxes. 
Ex: If I print 6 textboxes earlier nd re enter another value as 3, what I suppose to print is 3 textboxes. But altogether it prints 3+6 , 9 text boxes. What is the error I have made?

Comment: Hmmmm, either it works fine here, http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V4EQh/, or I'm misunderstanding the issue. I entered nine text boxes, hit the button and it generated the nine. Then I entered four, and it was only four, not 13.

Comment: :) 1) Click on "Click for Child Selections" button..

2) An alert will display... 

3) Then enter a value. ex: 4

4)Press OK..

5) Then u will see the problem I have.... If it is not either clear please let me knw...U might be clicking on "Click button" It works well...... :) Thank U....

Comment: Ah, OK I see it now. One issue I see is in the line `$(item).after("<br><div id='BtnSet>` you forgot to close the quote. Another issue is that this chunk of code will duplicate the ID of every element it appends which is a no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is in this logic:

- You are missing an ending "'" in the id
- Multiple elements with id='BtnSet' will be added to the document.
- You are clearing `#BtnSet` but the `<br>` elements will remain

You can clean this up quite a bit by wrapping each row in a containing element and using additional markers on your elements for selecting rather than just ID's.

I'd also recommend removing all the `&nbsp;` and `<br>`'s you are using for positioning and use CSS instead.

I believe this update code will do what you are trying to do without changing too much of your original markup and code:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/TkmRW/)</kbd>

```
function AddingTextBoxes() {
    var NumOfText = $("#NumOfTextBoxes").val();
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').empty();
    for (i = 1; i <= NumOfText; i++) {
        var ipBoxName = "MyInput" + i;

        // Wrap your row in a containing div with a class of 'jsRow'
        var $div = $('<div/>').addClass('jsRow');
        var txtBoxAutoNumbering = "<input type='text' name='textbx[]' id='TxtBx" + i + "'     style='width:50px;' value=" + i + " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $div.append(txtBoxAutoNumbering);
        var txtBox = "<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
        $div.append(txtBox);

        var Select_SelectionOptions = "<select id='SelectOption'><option>Text_Box</option><option>Text_Area</option><option>Radio_Button</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $div.append(Select_SelectionOptions);

        var Select_For_Multiple_Choices = "<button type='button' onclick='ChildTxtBoxes(this)' id='Child_Btn" + i + "' value='B'>Click for child selections</button><br>";
        $div.append(Select_For_Multiple_Choices);
        $div.appendTo($('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes'));
    }
    return false;
}

function ChildTxtBoxes(item) {
    // Use nextUntil to remove any divs with class `BtnSet` after it
    $(item).nextUntil('.jsRow').remove();
    var retVal = prompt("Enter the number of textboxes need to add");

    for (i = 1; i <= retVal; i++) {
        $(item).after("<div class='BtnSet' i><input id='TxtID" + i + "' type='text' name='textbx[]'/></div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: :) thank you vry much.... Well.... By coding what Im finally trying to do is, to create a dynamic form..... This is the part of an admin. this is where he enters colums names and their types... Should work more to build it up to that... Bt what I need to know is will I be able to convert it into a table finally? Are these steps im doing correct?

Comment: And could you please explain me more, how this $(item).nextUntil('.jsRow').remove(); will work?

Comment: `nextUntil` here is saying: starting with `$(item)` give me its next siblings until `'.jsRow'` is encountered.  `.remove()` is then called on the resulting collection removing those items from the document.

Comment: Given where you are going with the code, something like [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/TkmRW/1/) may help as it provides a bit more structure to some of the relationships.

Comment: It works really really fine in Fiddle sir... But again I have met some issues with the answer... I will edit my earlier question with your new answer could you please go through with it and let me know what the problem is? There I have put an alert.. After I clicked OK the whole text boxes dissapear... Please be kind enough to tell me the error what I have made... And could you please describe me the meaning of these two? 
var $this   = $(this);
 var idBase  = 'TxtID_' + $this.attr('id').split('_').slice(-1) + '_';

Comment: Where you are doing the alert, add `return false;` and it should begin working as you are expecting.  jQuery will call the event handler in the context of the element that triggered the event.  `this` is the actual element.  `$(this)` converts `this` to a jQuery object.  I use $ in my variable names to indicate when that variable is a jQuery object.  The `slice` logic is getting the elements numeric index from its id create a new id in the form `TxtID_[n]_[idx]` where `n` is the parents assigned index and `idx` is the new index for the child. It ensures there are no duplicate ID's.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TkmRW/2/

Im trying to generic this... If I click on any "Click for child selection" button , I need to create those three elements.. Even to its child buttons... Is it possible to do with this?

Comment: Yes - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/TkmRW/4/)  Look for my comments inline.

Comment: :) thats wt I wanted upto now... Nd had a good understanding too ... thankx alot sir....

Comment: I wrote a php code.......... to covert descriptions we enter into a form.... It worked... Now I need to show its child description attributes inside its parent's colum,, For that I feel I need to check whether row jsRow class has a BtnSet class and if so add a specified set of colums defines in using "ClickforChildSelection". Could u plz let me knw the mistake I have made....http://jsfiddle.net/TkmRW/6/

Comment: @Hiruni I think this is different enough from the original question that you should post it as a new question.

Comment: :) oki did it.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885601/check-whether-row-jsrow-class-has-a-btnset-class-using-a-php-file?noredirect=1#comment27874398_18885601